Duplicate Session Entry and Missing Session Support
I'm building a Discord bot dashboard API using NestJS, Passport, and TypeORM for session management. When a user attempts to log in through Discord, I encounter two errors:
[Nest] 19524  - 09.08.2024 15:03:10   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Duplicate entry '[access_token]' for key 'sessions.PRIMARY'
QueryFailedError: Duplicate entry 'mBU1jFgl3Q8crGxFJbuYrImdz3tk3cj6' for key 'sessions.PRIMARY'
    at Query.onResult (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\typeorm\driver\src\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.ts:246:33)
    at Query.execute (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:36:14)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:481:34)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:97:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:104:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)

[Nest] 19524  - 09.08.2024 15:03:18   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Login sessions require session support. Did you forget to use `express-session` middleware?
Error: Login sessions require session support. Did you forget to use `express-session` middleware?
    at SessionStrategy.authenticate (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\passport\lib\strategies\session.js:97:41)
    at attempt (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:378:16)
    at authenticate (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:379:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at initialize (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\initialize.js:98:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\starjin-client\starjin-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

I've implemented a session entity using TypeORM:
import { ISession } from 'connect-typeorm';
import {
  Column,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  Entity,
  Index,
  PrimaryColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity('sessions')
export class Session implements ISession {
  @Index()
  @Column('bigint')
  expiredAt: number;

  @PrimaryColumn('varchar', { length: 255 })
  id: string;

  @Column('text')
  json: string;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt?: Date;
}

main.ts:
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as passport from 'passport';
import { config } from './config';
import { TypeormStore } from 'connect-typeorm';
import { SessionService } from './session/session.service';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const sessionService = app.get(SessionService);

  app.use(
    session({
      secret: config.sessionSecret,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      },
      store: new TypeormStore().connect(sessionService.getSessionRepository()),
    }),
  );

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
  });

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
}
bootstrap();

discord.strategy.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Profile, Strategy } from 'passport-discord';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { config } from '../../config';

@Injectable()
export class DiscordStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'discord') {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      clientID: config.discordClientId,
      clientSecret: config.discordClientSecret,
      callbackURL: config.discordCallbackUrl,
      scope: ['identify', 'email', 'guilds'],
    });
  }

  async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: Profile,
    done: (error: any, user?: any) => void,
  ) {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser({
      avatar: profile.avatar,
      email: profile.email,
      global_name: profile.global_name,
      id: profile.id,
      username: profile.username,
      access_token: accessToken,
      refresh_token: refreshToken,
    });
    if (user) {
      done(null, user);
    } else {
      done(new Error('User not found'), null);
    }
  }
}

session.serializer.ts:
import { PassportSerializer } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SERVICES } from '../../utils/constants';

export class SessionSerializer extends PassportSerializer {
  constructor(
    @Inject(SERVICES.AUTH) private readonly authService: AuthService,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  serializeUser(user: any, done: (error: any, user?: any) => void) {
    console.log('serialize');
    done(null, user);
  }

  async deserializeUser(payload: any, done: (error: any, user?: any) => void) {
    console.log('deserialize');
    const user = await this.authService.findUserById(payload.id);
    return user ? done(null, user) : done(null, null);
  }
}

auth.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { IUser } from './dtos/user.type';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from '../utils/typeorm/entities/user.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  async validateUser(profile: IUser): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({
      where: { id: profile.id },
    });
    if (user) {
      return user;
    }

    // Create a new user if not found
    const newUser = this.userRepository.create(profile);
    return await this.userRepository.save(newUser);
  }

  async findUserById(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { id } });
  }
}

auth.module.ts:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { DiscordStrategy } from './utils/discord.strategy';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from '../utils/typeorm/entities/user.entity';
import { SessionSerializer } from './utils/session.serializer';
import { SERVICES } from '../utils/constants';
import { Session } from '../utils/typeorm/entities/session.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Session])],
  providers: [
    DiscordStrategy,
    SessionSerializer,
    { provide: SERVICES.AUTH, useClass: AuthService },
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}

I've tried ensuring correct configuration of express-session and Passport middleware. I expected the session to be created successfully and the user to be authenticated. However, the duplicate session entry and missing session support errors prevent successful login.

can you add the passportjs cconfiguration

@DileepaMabulage I added.

and the auth service code

@DileepaMabulage Added. To mention, when I try to authorize through Discord, it saves the session data (access_token etc.) to database (though it still throws Duplicate entry error), and I can see the cookie on my browser. However when I try to access to session data, it throws the [Nest] 17548  - 10.08.2024 16:44:51   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Login sessions require session support. Did you forget to use express-session middleware? error.

Your session configs seem correct, I doubt that validateUser function in AuthService. Can you check every time is the user getting null

@DileepaMabulage I checked all of them, not null, but when the user is not in the database its returning null in first check which is normal. I can see user and session in the database. Also when I restart NestJS, all of the problems are gone and I can use it without issues.

@DileepaMabulage you got any idea?
